# Using login with DownloadString failure

Tags: c#

So I've been coding a program which has a login system from my website and it downloads the string. I've tried reentering passwords and usernames in my website, but everytime I've done that, it still says no. Can you help me out?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MaterialSkin;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MaterialSkin.Controls;

namespace MemGen
{
    public partial class Form1 : MaterialForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<string> users = new List<string>();
        List<string> pass = new List<string>();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var url = "https://cajunpridetransportation.000webhostapp.com/login/login.txt";
            var client = new WebClient();
            using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] components = line.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    users.Add(components[0]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (users.Contains(textBox1.Text) && pass.Contains(textBox2.Text) && Array.IndexOf(users.ToArray(), textBox1.Text) == Array.IndexOf(pass.ToArray(), textBox2.Text))
            {
                frmMain form1 = new frmMain();
                form1.Show();
            } else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The username and/or password was incorrect", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you loading the `pass` variable? Also, it is extremely weird to download plain text passwords from the internet for local verification. Normally, you would POST your current username and password and the service would tell you whether they are correct

Comment: button1_Click Is where I'm loading it

Comment: [This](https://cajunpridetransportation.000webhostapp.com/login/login.txt) works just fine in the browser. What it's the exception you are getting?
[This works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1EHdTT)

Comment: It works. I didn't clarify the password strings.